# The hiring problem with already k empolyees and calculating the probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

The question as follows:
< both n,k are positive integers.
Let's look at the version of the employment problem in which we open a team of  engineers in the company.
The company receives  candidates in random order. We will denote the candidates by 1,…, , where 1 is the worst candidate for the job and  is the best.
First, the team is established with the participation of the first  candidates who come to the company. Then, for all new candidate  : If  is better than the worst candidate in the current team, then he will join the team in its place.

question 1) For some >−, calculate the probability that  will be a member of the team at some stage

//
what they want with calculating the probability in this question is to define an indicator for the Xi= event that makes a candidate ai to be accepted in the company and eventually calculating the expected value E[Xi]

my suggested answer is that to use the base hiring problem and change the limit groups, for example they want the group of n-k<i≤n instead of 1≤i≤n in the base problem, so:
the |omega|=k! , because we have k candidates to choose from, then :
Pr[Xi=1]= |Xi=1||omega|= P(n,i-(n-k+1))*P(n-i,n-i)\k!=1(2n-i-k+1)
//the P(n-i,n-i) comes from the fact that there's still n-i candidates to choose from the remainder n-i
I'm a bit skeptic about my answer here cuz it feels like there should no n-k on the left side of i index , and at the same time I feel like we should include k in the answer because we had k workers at the  beginning so it makes more sense to include it.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: An easier way is to consider whether candidate $a_i$ is in the top $k$ of the first $i$ candidates with $i\ge k$ and so is put into the team at least temporarily.  Given the "random order", this is simply $\frac{k}{i}$.